# How can I locate element by 'className1' or 'className2'?

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

So, in my project all my locators are the elements of enum and looks like:

if it is a css locator - `DIV_LOCATION("css=div.location-text.text-overflow")`. It parse the string and if starts with `css=` it know that it is a css locator.

If it is a xpath locator - `DIV_HEADER_GRP_TITLE("//*[contains(@class,'conversation-title')]//div")`

I want to write the universal css locator that will locate this two elements: `<div class = 'conv-title'>...</div>` and `<div class = 'conversation-title'>...</div>`

How can I do it?

The locator must starts with `css=`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Showing at least minimal effort put into solving an issue is required on StackOverflow.

Comment: What's stopping you from renaming the classes so they are the same - if they are the same element then use the same class, after all, that's what classes are for - sharing the same style amongst similar elements

Comment: @Pete, I haven't access to html.

Comment: hahaha too many "web developers" in the world today that don't have access to their html!  Very strange

Comment: @pete, I'm not a web developer exactly... But automation engeneer.

Answer (score 1):

`cssSelector` has or `,`

```
By.cssSelector(".conversation-title, .conv-title")
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please tell us what does `,` donates in css selector. I know `.` is for class but  Is `,` use for joint like we have **and** in xpath ?

Comment: @cruisepandey It's or, I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for info. I did not pay too much attention to the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

CSS for above element,
suppose element type is input

css = input[class*="conv"]

it will search with the class containing 'conv'